# angular service/config to populate text as required into component but want to add html also

Tags: html, angular, service

**service/config file:**

```
import { Injectable } from "@angular/core";
import { SafeHtml } from "@angular/platform-browser";
@Injectable()
export class xxxxxConfig {
  xxxVaultLink: SafeHtml;
  whatHappensNextItemsForEmailxxx: string[];
  whatHappensNextItemsForEmailSubTextxxx: string[];

  constructor() {
    this.xxxVaultLink = `<a href="https://www.w3schools.com" target="_blank">xxx xx</a>`;
    this.whatHappensNextItemsForEmailxxx = [
      `Confirmation of payment and a copy of your receipt has been emailed to you. You should receive it shortly.`,

      `xxxx will send your xxxxxdocuments (xxxxx) by post within 5 days.`,

      `A copy of your renewal xxxxx along with any supporting docs can be found in your 
       ${this.xxxVaultLink} within the next 2 - 3 days.`,
    ];

    this.whatHappensNextItemsForEmailSubTextxxx = [
      `(If you wish to receive your receipt by post, please contact us on 08xxxxx)`,

      `Important: please ensure that you keep your documents safe as they form the basis of your xxxx with xxx.`,

      ``,
    ];
```

}

I'm trying to add a link to the third item in the array above i.e. ${this.xxxVaultLink} but it shows all of the html including tags i.e. <\a href="https://www.w3schools.com" target="_blank">xxx xx</a>
Accessing it from the component below

**Component file:**

```
whatHappensNext() {
    if (!this.isxxxxy) {
        this.whatHappensNextItems = this.isxxxxPhoneNumber
          ? this.xxxxConfig.whatHappensNextItemsForEmailxxx
          : this.xxxxConfig.whatHappensNextItemsForPost;

        this.whatHappensNextItemsSubText = this.isxxxxPhoneNumber
          ? this.xxxxConfig.whatHappensNextItemsForEmailSubTextxxx
          : this.xxxxConfig.whatHappensNextItemsForPostSubText;

    }
}
```

Not sure if this makes sense but it would be great if one of you guys could tell me how to display the html/link in this config/service file

Answer (score 0):

You're missing possibly the most important part, which is the template showing us how you're attempting to show these string values.

I'll take a stab in the dark and assume it's something like this:

```
<div>{{myText}}</div>
```

If you want to slap some HTML in there, try this:

```
<div [innerHTML]="myText"></div>
```